# Javascript looping through a JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

Ok, a little new to JSON format..

I have the following JSON string returned from an AJAX call, which firebug actually displays in a tree quite nicely.. however I can't seem to be able to work out how to loop through the content...

```
{"data":{"item":[{"@id":"7","fromMemberID":"7","FromMember":"david","notificationsType":"event","notificationsDesc":"A new event (Test Event Thursday, 16 September 2010) has been created.","notificationsDate":"16 Sep 2010","notificationsTime":"00:02:18"},{"@id":"8","fromMemberID":"7","FromMember":"david","notificationsType":"event","notificationsDesc":"A new event (Test Event Thursday, 16 September 2010) has been created.","notificationsDate":"16 Sep 2010","notificationsTime":"08:26:24"}]}}
```

I have tried to say get a count of items.. alert(data.item.length);
or a loop:

```
for(i=0; i<data.item.length; i++)
{
    alert(data.item[i].FromMember);
}
```

obviously missing something fundemental...

Any ideas??

Comment: Did you convert the JSON string to JavaScript object?

Comment: @William, lol - there should be a "new comment has been posted" notification, like there is for answers.

Comment: :) sometimes it's hard to decide whether to do a comment or an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close... "data" is actually a key in your JSON, so you have to refer to your JSON variable to access "data".... so you want `JSON.data.item[i].FromMember`

Here is some full working code:

```
(function () {
    var json = {"data":{"item":[{"@id":"7","fromMemberID":"7","FromMember":"david","notificationsType":"event","notificationsDesc":"A new event (Test Event Thursday, 16 September 2010) has been created.","notificationsDate":"16 Sep 2010","notificationsTime":"00:02:18"},{"@id":"8","fromMemberID":"7","FromMember":"david","notificationsType":"event","notificationsDesc":"A new event (Test Event Thursday, 16 September 2010) has been created.","notificationsDate":"16 Sep 2010","notificationsTime":"08:26:24"}]}};

    var i;
    var iLength = json.data.item.length;
    for (i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
        alert(json.data.item[i].FromMember);
    }
})();​
```

### **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYDjV/)**

Answer (score 5):

The JSON object is a standard in the new browsers. For older browsers you can add the javascript library [json2.js from json.org](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) (2.5kb minified).

To transform the string to an object, use `JSON.parse`

```
var response = JSON.parse('{"data":{"ite...ime":"08:26:24"}]}}'),
    item = response.data.item;
```

And to send back your data to the server, use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(theObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use de-serialize the JSON.

```
var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);
```

Depends on which JavaScript frameworks you are using, each has it's own de-serializer.

The above example is using the MicrosoftAjax.js library.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310857.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you should have something like this for it to work. notice the `obj` in the `for-loop`.

```
var obj = {"data":{"item":[{"@id":"7","fromMemberID":"7","FromMember":"david","notificationsType":"event","notificationsDesc":"A new event (Test Event Thursday, 16 September 2010) has been created.","notificationsDate":"16 Sep 2010","notificationsTime":"00:02:18"},{"@id":"8","fromMemberID":"7","FromMember":"david","notificationsType":"event","notificationsDesc":"A new event (Test Event Thursday, 16 September 2010) has been created.","notificationsDate":"16 Sep 2010","notificationsTime":"08:26:24"}]}};

for (i = 0; i < obj.data.item.length; i++) {
    alert(obj.data.item[i].FromMember);
}​
```

or if you have `data` as your variable, still you should call it as `data.data.item.length.`

Comment: Thank you! yes, strange thing.. the JSON data was essentially a string rather than an object! thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your json to the function below.

```
function getData(obj) {
    var myData = obj.data.item, i, output = '';

    for (i = 0; i < myData.length; i += 1) {
        for (key in myData[i]) {
         output += key + " : " + myData[i][key];
        }       
    }
    return output;
}
```

[Click for example](http://jsfiddle.net/3pBuk/)

Comment: Thank you! yes, it looked like the JSON data was coming back as a string rather than an object..